# How to loop sql data into array and adding keys?

Tags: javascript, json

i would like to know how to loop all of my sql datas (that i parsed into a json table) into an array, with adding a key to each of them.

I know how i can loop all of the data into an simple string like this :

```
var dbString ="";
for(i = 0; i < result.response.length; i++) 
{
    dbString += result.response[i].names;
}
```

This would just look like this

```
var dbString = "James Michael Alfred....";
```

But how can i make this look like this :

```
var dbString = {"James":1, "Michael":2, "Alfred":3, .....}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the number value supposed to be the row number/index?

Comment: No, keys so i can get the value of those with a variable like Object.keys(dbString). I use it for a search function

Comment: If you're just going to call `Object.keys`, and the values are just indexes, you might as well put the names in an array, instead of the keys of an object.

Comment: Seems legit, ill try to rewrite it, seems easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a really unique demand to organise a list of names like you want, but here it is:

```
var dbString = {};
var names = result.response;
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    dbString[names[i]] = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that in a few minutes, thanks for the answer

Comment: It is working so far, but i have a problem, the array is not sorted by the keys. Its like    { alfred : 4, michael : 1, James: 5, .... }

Comment: objects like `{"alfred": 4, "michael": 1, ...}` cannot be sorted , you can use arrays for that like `["michael", "alfred, ...]` and access elements by index (e.g. `array[0]` -> "michael")

Comment: What is did was, just changing the places so it easily loops the "i". `dbString[i+1] = names[i];`

Comment: that is almost like an array (except that an array is zero-based). why do you insist on using object instead of an array?